# How to assert what given method pointer uses stdcall calling convention?

Tags: delphi, rtti

In my library i'm invoking methods under specific conditions, which requires stdcall calling convention. Currently i'm using compiler static resolution, implemented as rather large list of well-known method signatures and corresponding overloaded versions of my subroutine. This works but looks quite fugly and doesnt 100% cover all possible methods. I would like to add a possibility to work with generic method pointer and assert proper calling convention by asking RTTI. And here i'm stuck, please advise.

```
Input: code/data pair of pointers as in TMethod 
Output: boolean indicator, true if method is stdcall
```

I'd preferable use "classic" RTTI to create less version dependencies, however i cant find any calling convention indicator within "classic" RTTI...

---

**NB: This question is UNRELATED to importing external functions**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract calling convention information from extended RTTI (available since Delphi 2010).

```
uses RTTI, TypInfo;

function GetMethCallConv(AMeth: TMethod; out Conv: TCallConv): Boolean;
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Meth: TRttiMethod;
  Typ: TRttiType;

begin
  Ctx:= TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    Typ:= Ctx.GetType(TObject(AMeth.Data).ClassType);
    for Meth in Typ.GetMethods do begin
      if Meth.CodeAddress = AMeth.Code then begin
        Conv:= Meth.CallingConvention;
        Exit(True);
      end;
    end;
    Exit(False);
  finally
    Ctx.Free;
  end;
end;

//test

type
  TMyObj = class
  public
    procedure MyMeth(I: Integer); stdcall;
  end;

procedure TMyObj.MyMeth(I: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
end;
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Conv: TCallConv;
  Meth: TMethod;
  MyObj: TMyObj;

begin
  MyObj:= TMyObj.Create;
  Meth.Code:= @TMyObj.MyMeth;
  Meth.Data:= MyObj;
  if GetMethCallConv(Meth, Conv) then begin
    case Conv of
      ccReg: ShowMessage('Register');
      ccCdecl: ShowMessage('cdecl');
      ccPascal: ShowMessage('Pascal');
      ccStdCall: ShowMessage('StdCall');
      ccSafeCall: ShowMessage('SafeCall');
    end;
  end;
  MyObj.Free;
end;
```

---

**Update**

For "classic" RTTI read Sertac answer; the following works OK on Delphi 2010:

```
uses ObjAuto;

function GetMethCallConv2(AMeth: TMethod; out Conv: TCallingConvention): Boolean;
var
  Methods: TMethodInfoArray;
  I: Integer;
  P: PMethodInfoHeader;

begin
  Result:= False;
  Methods:= GetMethods(TObject(AMeth.Data).ClassType);
  if not Assigned(Methods) then Exit;

  for I:= Low(Methods) to High(Methods) do begin
    P:= Methods[I];
    if P^.Addr = AMeth.Code then begin
      Inc(Integer(P), SizeOf(TMethodInfoHeader) - SizeOf(ShortString) + 1 +
        Length(PMethodInfoHeader(P)^.Name));
      Conv:= PReturnInfo(P).CallingConvention;
      Result:= True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

{$TYPEINFO ON}
{$METHODINFO ON}
type
  TMyObj = class
  public
    procedure MyMeth(I: Integer);
  end;

procedure TMyObj.MyMeth(I: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
end;

procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Conv: TCallingConvention;
  Meth: TMethod;
  MyObj: TMyObj;

begin
  MyObj:= TMyObj.Create;
  Meth.Code:= @TMyObj.MyMeth;
  Meth.Data:= MyObj;
  if GetMethCallConv2(Meth, Conv) then begin
    case Conv of
      ccRegister: ShowMessage('Register');
      ccCdecl: ShowMessage('cdecl');
      ccPascal: ShowMessage('Pascal');
      ccStdCall: ShowMessage('StdCall');
      ccSafeCall: ShowMessage('SafeCall');
    end;
  end;
  MyObj.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! How about "classic" RTTI?

Answer (score 3):

Including Delphi 7 and up, when [`METHODINFO`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsmethodinfo_xml.html) directive is on, run-time generates information about, at least having public visibility, method parameters and return types and calling convention (`TYPEINFO` should also be on).

Not sure if the below sample would help you directly since it works on an instance and method's name and not its address, but perhaps you can construct a look-up table for name-address of methods beforehand.

```
type
{$METHODINFO ON}
  TSomeClass = class
  public
    procedure Proc1(i: Integer; d: Double); stdcall;
    procedure Proc2;
  end;
{$METHODINFO OFF}

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FSomeClass: TSomeClass;

  ..

uses
  objauto;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSomeClass := TSomeClass.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Info: Pointer;
begin
  Info := GetMethodInfo(FSomeClass, 'Proc1');
  if Assigned(Info) then begin
    Inc(Integer(Info), SizeOf(TMethodInfoHeader) - SizeOf(ShortString) + 1 +
      Length(PMethodInfoHeader(Info).Name));
    if PReturnInfo(Info).CallingConvention = ccStdCall then
      // ...

  end;
```

Beware and do some testing though, tested on D2007 the working is somewhat unpredictable. For instance, if the above 'Proc1' is changed to `procedure Proc1(i: Pointer; d: Double);` no detailed RTTI is generated.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning METHODINFO, present in D7 compiler, but missing from documentation.

Comment: @user - You're welcome! If you need to go into more details of *classic* RTTI, I can recommend you [Hallvard Vassbotn's blog](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

See here on how to find out:

http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#cconvs

IOW, you can simply try if it works, or you take a look at the exported name (_name@17 or similar) or you take a look at a disassembly, e.g. in the CPU view.

Comment: please highlight unclear parts in my question, because it is not about importing headers at all. BTW, trial-and-error is very bad approach in any case, with some luck subroutine invoked with wrong calling convention may not crash immediately cause undefined behaviour elsewhere.

Comment: @Serg then I probably misunderstood.